# How do I parse this string with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
"GOOG",625.00,"-1.95 - -0.31%"
```

I'm using this pattern, and it isn't matching. I'm trying to get GOOG. What am I doing wrong?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\"([^\"]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    Log.i(TAG, matcher.group(0));
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "no match");
}
```

Comment: The pattern looks fine to me -- can you verify by writing out the first few characters that "line" doesn't begin with a newline or something crazy like that?

Comment: Using regex to *parse* something is dead inefficient. Rather use it to *match* something and use a fullworthy parser to parse something. For CSV there exist [CSV parsers](http://google.com/search?q=java+csv+parser) (as HTML parsers exist for HTML...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's `matches()` method expects the regex to match the whole string, as if it were anchored at both ends with `^` and `$` (or `\A` and `\z`).  Whenever you use `matches()` with a regex that only matches part of the string, you need to "pad" the regex with `.*`, like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    Log.i(TAG, matcher.group(1));  // not group(0)!
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "no match");
}
```

The `^` at the beginning of the regex wasn't doing any harm, I just removed it to show that it wasn't necessary.  Notice that I also changed your `group(0)` to `group(1)`--that was another error in your code. `group(0)` is the whole match, while `group(1)` refers only to the part that was matched in the first set of capturing parentheses.

You also have the option of using `find()`, like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

if (matcher.find()) {
    Log.i(TAG, matcher.group(1));
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "no match");
}
```

This matches the first instance of a quotation mark followed by one or more characters other than quotation marks (which are captured in group #1).  That will match anywhere; if you want it to match only at the very beginning of the string, you have to use the `^` anchor as you had it in your original regex: `"^\"([^\"]+)"`

(There's also a `lookingAt()` method, which automatically anchors the match to the beginning of the string but not the end, but nobody ever uses it.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're not running `matcher.find()` so the expression is never really evaluated.  What you have will work fine if you just change it to:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
```

Though this seems like it'd be easier if you just used the `String.split` method (or better yet, use a library for parsing CSV files):

```
String temp = "\"GOOG\",625.00,\"-1.95 - -0.31%\"";
String[] parts = temp.split(",");
String symbol = temp[0].replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: "(or better yet, **[use] a library for parsing CSV files**)"

Comment: Assuming `GOOG` will never have a comma in it but I think that's unlikely since it would annoy a lot of stock traders :-)

Answer (score 0):

you first need to call matcher.find()

```
String temp = "\"GOOG\",625.00,\"-1.95 - -0.31%\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"[a-zA-Z]*\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);

if(matcher.find()){
    Log.i(TAG, matcher.group(0).split("\"")[1]);  
} else {  
    Log.i(TAG, "no match");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try thi Regex :

```
^"(?<text>[^"]+?)"
```

I think you were missing second " (the one after GOOG")

EDIT :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

Comment: `(?<XYZ>...)` is how you specify a *named group*, but Java regexes don't support those yet (they're coming in Java 7).  And leaving off the second quote is not an error in this case; the `[^\"]+` will stop matching when it runs out of non-quotes.  (But I would add the closing quote anyway, to avoid confusion.)